# On Cryptowatch (or equivalent): see percentage change to custom reference point

Tags: exchange-rate

Given that I bought a certain amount of BTC at a given point in time. Is there a way on [cryptowat.ch](http://cryptowat.ch) or an equivalent platform, to mark the price and point of time at which I bought the BTCs and get information about how the current price is to the reference price in percent (preferably live)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added on 18.01.2017. See [Changelog](https://www.reddit.com/r/cryptowatch/comments/7owfqy/changelog_1718_sunday_night_chart_updates/)

Answer (score 1):

Not the way you are putting it but i update my portfolio on 
https://www.worldcoinindex.com/portfolio

This allows me to see in euro/usd and others.
For example you bought 1000 usd of any combination of currencies.
This profile wil tell you what it's worth approx (different markets have slight changes between them).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this - just set your Y-axis to percentage. Then hover the crosshair over your buy pin. The corresponding reading on the Y-axis should show you P/L in %

[image]